# Increment and Decrement Operators

Tags: c, increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x = 4, y, z;
  y = --x;
  z = x--;
  printf("%d %d %d", x, y, z);
}
```

Output: `2 3 3`

Can anyone explain this?
And what does `i =+ j` mean (suppose `i = 1` and `j = 2`)?

Comment: should be `int main()` and the `'\n'` in printf should be at the end

Comment: hi, ive shown you visually what happens to your code. so you can understand it in an easy way going step by step through your code to let you know what happens. and so that you can explain it as well by referring to your code. check it out

Comment: What exactly do you want explained? The behavior is perfectly expected. It is like asking to explain "2 + 2 = 4". If see something specific in the output that you want explained - you have to point it out. If not, read you favorite C book for basic explanations of C operators.

Comment: @pmg: The '\n' being at the end or the beginning is an output decision.  '\n' at the end probably makes more sense, but maybe the it doesn't.  Making main an int and having the program return 0 is a change that should be made, of course.

Comment: @Brian: in this program the position ofthe '\n' is irrelevant because the program terminates right after the printf and the output stream is flushed. But, as a matter of principle, I always end the printfs with '\n'

Comment: @pmg: I have my doubts about the exact intent of that part of the specification, but C standard states that some implementations might *require* text streams to have an `\n` at the end of the last line. (I.e. the language might not define the behavior if the last line of a text stream is not ended with `\n`)

Comment: @Andrey: I know I've been bitten by the absence of that last '\n', but I can't remember the program that bit me. Anyway, my documentation for `getline` (not in the Standard) says it "returns -1 on failure to read a line (including end of file condition)". Maybe I was bitten by a program that uses `getline`? ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**simple explanation:**

**--x or ++x**  : Value will be modified after.

**x-- or x++** : Value will be modified before

**Detailed explanation:**

**--x or ++x**: *pre-decrement/increment:* will first do the operation of decrementing or incrementing first, then it will assign x.

**x-- or x++**: *post:decrement/increment*: will first assign the value of x and then it will do the operation of decrementing or incrementing after.

lets write your code in a nicer format and go through your code step by step and annotate it to show you visually what happens:

```
main() {
    //We declare the variables x, y and z, only x is given a value of 4.
    int x=4,y,z;

    //--x will decrement var x by 1 first THEN it will assign the value of x to y.
    //so: x = 3, y = 3 and z = nothing yet.
    y = --x;

    //x-- will assign the value of x to z first, then var x will be decremented by 1 after.
    //so: x = 2, y=3 and z = 3
    z = x--; 

    printf ("\n %d %d %d", x,y,z);

}
```

Comment: OK i got it Thanks for the detailed description.I have one more thing: What does this means ; i=+j;

Comment: that would not work, it means nothing. only += and others of its kind will work. += -= *= /= %= and so on.... they are assignment operators.
y += x is equivelant as y = y + x. any more questions id be willing to help. although =+ works in perl. then again perl is crazy, it allows you to do anything. :D

Comment: So what should it supposed to do if its allowed.

Comment: sorry even in perl it doesnt work. It doesnt do anything. it will just give an error.

Comment: =  Normal Assignment, 
+=  Add and Assign, 
-=  Subtract and Assign, 
*=  Multiply and Assign, 
/=  Divide and Assign, 
%=  Modulus and Assign and 
**=     Exponent and Assign.

Comment: I was just going through some programming practice and i came across this and the question say it should work and asking for output.#include<stdio.h>
main ()
{
int i=1, j=1;
for (;;)
{
if (i>5)
break;
else
j+=i;


printf ("\n%d", j);


i=+j;


}
}

Comment: some stuff provided to me. Don't know which book it is from.

Comment: yeah theres a mistake . the person that wrote it made a mistake. because that assignment operator doesnt exist and will not work
you have my word

Comment: it should be either i += j... or i = i+ j. Just like in your code fragment it says j+=i so i believe its the same for the first one. So its most likely i += j instead of i =+j.

Comment: Alright Thanks for looking so deep into this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: "Koi gal nahi pagi" - No problem bro

Comment: In old, *old* versions of C the compound assignment operators could take that form (http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V50_HTML/ARH9NATE/DOCU_026.HTM#3_1_5_), so the book might just be ancient.  But in all likelihood, it's a typo.

Answer (score 9):

`y = --x` means "decrease x by one, then store the result in y"

`z = x--` means "save a temp of x. Decrease x by one. Store the temp value in z"

Hence:

- x starts at 4.
- It gets decreased by 1 (to 3). 3 is stored in y.
- x is saved to a temp. x is decreased again (to 2). then the temp (3) is stored in z.
- y and z are printed as 3, x is printed as 2.

Comment: -1: This is not precisely true.  x-- means, "save a temp of x.  Decrease x by one.  Return the temp value".  This distinction usually does not make a difference, but there are weird situations (usually involving poorly written code) where this behavior becomes relevant.  It is also relevant if you are attempting to implement an increment operator yourself.

Comment: +1 For corrected explanation.  As an aside, this distinction is also relevant due to micro-optimizations (i.e. Where possible, preincrement is consdered better than post-increment since no temp is needed).

Comment: @Brian: For built-in types, a compiler is generally free to implement postincrement as "save value, increment, use temp", or "increment and use (new_value-1)", or "use value, then increment sometime later as convenient".  Too bad no such facility was provided for user-defined post-increment operators.

Comment: Your explanation of `z = x++;` is misleading because it implies that C requires such a ridiculously inefficient procedure. A better explanation would be: "Store the value of `x` in `z`, then increment `x`." The side effect of postfix `++` should be thought of as happening at the next sequence point, not immediately mid-expression.

Comment: @Supercat: This is true, but that is an optimization.  Further, there are situations (involving poorly written code) where that optimization is not possible without changing the meaning of the code.

Comment: @Brian: If, between two sequence points, code uses a pre-increment or post-increment operator on a non-volatile variable and does anything else with that variable, the C standard allows the compiler to do //anything it wants//, up to and including working as expected, crashing, redirecting all your bookmarks at iLoveBarney.com, or anything else.  If the behavior of someone's code would be affected by the changes I listed, the person should consider themselves lucky the compiler hasn't done something more "creative".

Answer (score 6):

The postfix decrement operator (x--) returns the value of the variable before it was decremented.

- x = 2, because you've decremented it
  twice.
- y = 3, because you've assigned
  it to the value of x *after* it was
  decremented from 4
- z = 3, because you've
  assigned it to the value of x
  *before* it was decremented from 3.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand the notions of post-decrement and pre-decrement operator.

Both will decrement your variable, but one of them will return the original value (`x--`) and one of them will return the decremented value (`--x`).

Answer (score 0):

Postfix decrement (x--) is different from prefix decrement (--x).
The former return the value x, then decrements it; the latter decrements and then returns the value.

And if you thing how a postfix is written at low level, you'll find that it is a liiiitle slower than the prefix... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
y = --x;
```

X is decremented, then Y is assigned with the value of X (3)

```
z = x--;
```

Z is assigned with the value of X (3), the X is decremented (2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

x = 4
y = pre-decrement x (basically decrement by 1 and then assign, i.e. y = x-1 = 3
x =3
z = post-decrement x (decrement by 1 *after* assigning the value, i.e. z = x = 3, then x = x - 1
x = 2

So x = 2, y = 3, z = 3, exactly what you saw.

Answer (score 0):

If the operator is a prefix the incrementation happens before the assignment, if the operator is a postfix the incrementation happens after the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

let `**` be an increment/decrement operator. `**e` means *apply `**` to `e` and evaluate the result* whereas `e**` means *evaluate `e` and then apply `**` to it*.

Ergo, if decrementation and evaluation are seperated, the code reads as:

```
int x=4,y,z;
x-=1;//3
y = x;//3
z = x;//3
x-=1;//2
```

which gives you the ouput you have ;)

Answer (score 0):

- **x++ / x--** is called *post* increment / decrement (value modified after...)
- **++x / ++x** is called *pre* increment / decrement (value modified before...)

Here is what happens (roughly) in your example :

```
int x=4,y,z;  // declare x=4, y=0, z=0
y = --x;      // decrement x then assign it to y (pre decrement) (y=x=3)
z = x--;      // assign x to z then decrement x (post decrement) (z=3 and x=2)
printf ("\n %d %d %d", x,y,z);  // output 2 3 3
```

A pre increment/decrement looks like this in pseudocode

```
read value
increment/decrement value
write value
assign value
```

and a post increment/decrement looks like this

```
read value
assign value
increment/decrement value
write value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main ()
{
int x=4,y,z;
y = --x;
z = x--;
printf ("\n %d %d %d", x,y,z);
}
```

output 2,3,3.................................first time x=4 fine. y=--x, means value of x is decremented by 1 and stored in y, thus now y=3 and x is also 3. then z=x-- means value of x is stored in z( z=3) and then x is decremented i.e now x=2 but z=3. when u r printing the value, then printf() prints 2 3 3

Answer (score 0):

Talking about what `i=+j;` means(given i=1 and j=2)

`i=+j;` is equivalent to `i=i+j;` so your expression becomes `i=1+2` i.e. `i=3`