# what is the difference between i-- and i-1 in C?

Tags: c

I have been trying to run a code for fibonacci series through recursion and used to pass fib(x, y, i--) which resulted in an infinite recursion while the same code worked well by using fib(x, y, i-1).
Is there any significant reason for this?

Comment: Yes, did you look at what `i--` does? You should read up on increment and decrement operators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment and Decrement Operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891230/increment-and-decrement-operators)

Comment: Aha, **fibonacci**. Ever seen the TV series Prison Break? You'll know what I'm talking about...

Comment: Please show your code. It sounds like you are missing your base cases. Both `0` and `1` should be provided.

Answer (score 2):

`i--` passes `i` to the function *then* decrements `i` value in the caller scope.

`i-1` passes `i-1` to the function and does not change `i` value in the caller scope.

So yes they're totally different. If `fib` calls itself, the same number is passed over and over again, resulting in infinite recursion

Answer (score 0):

First of all consider that using `i-1` your result will be the value of `i` minus 1, but the variable `i` will retain its initial value (there is no assignment). Conversely the use of increment or decrement operators **modify the variable** (in this case there is assignment. I.e. `i++` is equivalent to `i=i+1`).

Said that, the operators `--`, decrement, and `++`, increment, come in two flavours: prefix (i.e. `++i`) and postfix (i.e. `i++`), the operation of increment or decrement is actuated respectively before or after the use of the expression value depending on where you put it.

While the expression `i-1` always execute the operation before to use the result (it behaves as a prefixed decrement operator), using increment or decrement operators as prefix the action, increment or decrement, is performed first then the result is used. On the other hand if the operator follow the expression, postfix, the value will be used, or passed, before the operator is applied.

In your case you are using **postdecrement** in something like:

```
void fib(int x, int y, int i)
{
    ...
    if (i = 0)
        return;
    fib(x, y, i--);
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    ...
    fib(10, 20, 30);
    ...
}
```

Each time you call `fib` you pass the initial value of `i`, then locally decrement its value. It will never become 0 in recursed calls, and your loop will never end.

If you use the **predecrement**, prefixing the operator to the expression (in this case the variable `i`), the behavior changes, the decrement is executed before to pass the value, and your program will work (the behavior is the same of `i-1`):

```
void fib(int x, int y, int i)
{
    ...
    if (i = 0)
        return;
    fib(x, y, --i);    //Note the prefix
    ...
}
```